# Group numbers by shortest prefix

Tags: vba

I understand this is not the ideal question for this site, but by the guidelines outlined in the community wiki (here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) I feel that it qualifies under algorithm.  Please flag for a move if it's not well placed, or comment and I will delete appropriately.

I have a list of numbers that I need to group by the shortest possible common starting numbers.

In the example below all numbers could be grouped by 12, as 12 followed by anything  will be owned by CompanyA :

```
120  CompanyA
121  CompanyA
122  CompanyA
123  CompanyA
124  CompanyA
125  CompanyA
126  CompanyA
127  CompanyA
128  CompanyA
129  CompanyA
```

To give a more realistic sample of my data (Numbers are between 3 and 6 digits):

```
3734 CompanyA
3735 CompanyA
375  CompanyA
3760 CompanyA
3761 CompanyA
3762 CompanyA
3763 CompanyA
3764 CompanyA
3765 CompanyA
3766 CompanyA
3767 CompanyA
3768 CompanyA
3769 CompanyA
3770 CompanyA
3771 CompanyA
3773   CompanyB
3774   CompanyB
3775   CompanyB
3776   CompanyB
3778   CompanyB
33045  CompanyB
361    CompanyB
```

Should become:

```
3734 CompanyA
3735 CompanyA
375  CompanyA
376  CompanyA  'All numbers from 3760 to 3769 have been condensed to 1 number
3770  CompanyA
3771  CompanyA
3773   CompanyB
3774   CompanyB
3775   CompanyB
3776   CompanyB
3778   CompanyB
33045  CompanyB
361    CompanyB
```

This is a problem which must permeate multiple industries, and I imagine there is an algorithm that I can adapt for VBA without too much difficulty.  I am, however, struggling with the logic.

If someone could point me in the right direction for this it would be appreciated.  I will happily adapt and post an answer in VBA if someone can point me in the right direction, unfortunately my googling abilities are failing me.

Comment: I doubt that you will find something that you can copy and paste. Most probably you will need to create a solution yourself.

Comment: Is there a logic for how deep the groupings should go or what they should apply to? For example, why wouldn't "3734 CompanyA" and "3735 CompanyA" get grouped down to "373 CompanyA". Also, how do you know how many digits a number represents? Is it always considered to be the visible numbers padded to a length of 9 on the right with 0?

Comment: @Blackhawk A number can be up to 8 digits, and for a 3 digit number to encompass a 4 digit one it must cover all permutations, ie it has to be explicitly stated that company A owns 3730-3739 to get grouped down to 373, if that makes sense?

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for the response.  I appreciate that, I'm not really looking for an answer to copy paste as such, more "you should look at preston's technique for prefixing".  I'm happy to create and post an answer myself as necessary, It's the logic I al really struggling with.

Comment: Well, the logic is simple. 1) start with the number for the first company name. 2) loop over the company names. 3) while they stay the same, compare numbers. take away digits from the right until the numbers match. 4) move on to the next company. 5) if company names change, start at 1). Sort by company name ascending and length of number descending beforehand.

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha - is it guaranteed that the list will always be in order?

Comment: If this needed to be more robust, it'd be fun to use a radix tree with a customizable recursive merging operation, but given the straightforward nature of the data and (I assume) the fact that it will most likely always be sorted, it would be overkill. I'll see if I can put something together.

Comment: @Blackhawk It can be ordered any way before applying a method.  I'll have a look at trees and recursive merging now.  If you do get any time to have a look at it it would be fully appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it took a bit more time than I anticipated, but here it is! In case you haven't worked with Tries before, I suggest [reading the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Basically, each level in the tree represents a character of the number. When the end of the number is reached down through the tree, it is a leaf, and this is where the value (company name) is stored. Admittedly, I did a spotty job of commenting the code, so if there's anything in particular you would like to know, comment and I can expand on it.

First, create a `clsTrieNode` class like so:

```
Option Explicit

Public parent As clsTrieNode
Public value As String
Public count As Long
Public digit As String

'Arrays are not allowed to be public members of classes, sadly
Private m_children(0 To 9) As clsTrieNode

Public Property Get children(i As Byte) As clsTrieNode
    Set children = m_children(i)
End Property

Public Property Set children(i As Byte, node As clsTrieNode)
    Set m_children(i) = node
End Property
```

Next, create the `clsNumberTrie` like so:

```
Option Explicit

Private head As clsTrieNode

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set head = New clsTrieNode
End Sub

Public Sub Add(key As String, value As String)
    Dim temp As clsTrieNode
    Set temp = head
    Dim i As Long
    Dim key_digit As Byte
    For i = 1 To Len(key)
        key_digit = Val(Mid(key, i, 1))
        If Not temp.children(key_digit) Is Nothing Then
            Set temp = temp.children(key_digit)
        Else
            Set temp.children(key_digit) = New clsTrieNode
            Set temp.children(key_digit).parent = temp
            Set temp = temp.children(key_digit)
            temp.digit = key_digit 'implicit string conversion
        End If
    Next
    temp.value = value
    mergeTrieUpwards temp.parent
End Sub

Private Sub mergeTrieUpwards(node As clsTrieNode)
    If isMergeable(node) Then
        node.value = node.children(0).value
        Dim i As Byte
        For i = 0 To 9
            Set node.children(i) = Nothing
        Next
        mergeTrieUpwards node.parent
    End If
End Sub

Private Function isMergeable(node As clsTrieNode) As Boolean
    Dim i As Byte
    'Firstly, node must be defined (e.g., not the parent of head)
    If node Is Nothing Then
        isMergeable = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = 0 To 9
        'Secondly, all children must be defined
        If node.children(i) Is Nothing Then
            isMergeable = False
            Exit Function
        'Thirdly, all children must be leaves
        ElseIf node.children(i).value = "" Then
            isMergeable = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    isMergeable = True
End Function

Public Function toString() As String
    Dim strKey As String
    Dim strOutput As String
    If Not head Is Nothing Then
        strOutput = toStringRecurse("", head)
    End If
    toString = strOutput
End Function

Private Function toStringRecurse(prefix As String, node As clsTrieNode) As String
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim i As Byte
    If node.value <> "" Then
        toStringRecurse = prefix & node.digit & " " & node.value & vbCrLf
        Exit Function
    Else
        For i = 0 To 9
            If Not node.children(i) Is Nothing Then
                strOutput = strOutput & toStringRecurse(prefix & node.digit, node.children(i))
            End If
        Next
        toStringRecurse = strOutput
    End If
End Function
```

Finally, to run it against your input numbers, I have the following in a module called `mdlMain`. I rolled my own Split because the built-in split doesn't support ignoring successive delimiters, and your input has variable numbers of spaces.

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim input_data As String
    input_data = "3734   CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3735   CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "375    CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3760   CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3761   CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3762   CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3763   CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3764   CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3765   CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3766   CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3767   CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3768   CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3769   CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3770   CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3771   CompanyA" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3773   CompanyB" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3774   CompanyB" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3775   CompanyB" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3776   CompanyB" & vbCrLf & _
                 "3778   CompanyB" & vbCrLf & _
                 "33045  CompanyB" & vbCrLf & _
                 "361    CompanyB"

    Dim companyTrie As clsNumberTrie
    Set companyTrie = New clsNumberTrie

    Dim rows As Variant
    Dim row As Variant

    rows = SplitStr(input_data, vbCrLf)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(rows)
        row = SplitStr(CStr(rows(i)), " ", True)
        companyTrie.Add CStr(row(0)), CStr(row(1))
    Next

    Debug.Print companyTrie.toString

End Sub

'This implementation of split has supports ignoring consecutive delimiters
Public Function SplitStr(str As String, delim As String, Optional treatSuccessiveDelimitersAsOne = False) As Variant
    'This is not an optimal implementation:
    '1. Resizing an array is expensive because it requires copying the whole thing.
    '2. String concatenation has the same problem; new memory is allocated to hold the result, and then both strings are copied to this new location.
    'Thankfully, with the small strings in this example, it doesn't matter too much.

    Dim i As Long
    Dim outArr() As String

    ReDim outArr(0 To 0)

    'Iterate through the string
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        'If the current character is the start of the delimiter...
        If Mid(str, i, 1) = Mid(delim, 1, 1) Then
            'Check and see if the whole delimiter is there...
            If isSubstringDelim(str, i, delim) Then
                'If so, jump i past the delimiter and add a new slot to the split array
                i = i + Len(delim)
                ReDim Preserve outArr(0 To (UBound(outArr) + 1))
                'Check to see if there are multiple delimiters in a row...
                While isSubstringDelim(str, i, delim)
                    i = i + Len(delim)
                    'If treatSuccessiveDelimitersAsOne is False, we add a blank string to the split array each time we encounter a successive delimiter.
                    'If it's true, just consume the delimiters without creating a blank string
                    If Not treatSuccessiveDelimitersAsOne Then
                        ReDim Preserve outArr(0 To (UBound(outArr) + 1))
                    End If
                Wend
            End If
        End If
        'Add the current character to the current slot of the split array
        outArr(UBound(outArr)) = outArr(UBound(outArr)) + Mid(str, i, 1)
    Next

    SplitStr = outArr
End Function

Private Function isSubstringDelim(str, index, delim) As Boolean
    Dim min As Long
    If (Len(str) - index) < Len(delim) Then
        isSubstringDelim = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    For i = 1 To Len(delim)
        If Not (Mid(str, i + index - 1, 1) = Mid(delim, i, 1)) Then
            isSubstringDelim = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    isSubstringDelim = True
End Function
```

The result is output in alphabetical order because of the way the nodes are visited. Note that it supports recursive grouping, so if you had 3351 through 3358 for CompanyA, but you also had 33591 through 33599 for CompanyA, it would roll up 3359 first, then rollup 335.

33045 CompanyB
361 CompanyB
3734 CompanyA
3735 CompanyA
375 CompanyA
376 CompanyA
3770 CompanyA
3771 CompanyA
3773 CompanyB
3774 CompanyB
3775 CompanyB
3776 CompanyB
3778 CompanyB

Comment: This looks like an excellent response, I'm grateful for the time and effort that you put in- it's far exceeded what I expected.  I haven't had the time to go through this, but I will tonight and more than likely accept the answer.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the string for the position of your characters, so if you test for '37' and it appears in the first position, your sting starts with 37 and you can add it to your list, move it, whatever you want to do.

```
If InStr(yourString,"37") < 2 Then 
    'do whatever 
End If
```

you might need to play around with the exact if statement and number, this is just to show you the general idea.

sorry, just read down to the bottom and saw that some start with 37 but are a different company.  for those I'd test on the 3rd character in the same way in a nested if, and split them off.